# can I delete virbr0 and virbr0-nic created by MAAS?

Tags: maas

When installing MAAS, it creates virbr0 and virbr0-nic and an associated fabric and subnet (e.g. 192.168.whatever).  What's the purpose of these? Can these be deleted from the OS (e.g. `ip link del`) and then can I delete the corresponding subnet and fabric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually not MAAS that installs virbr0 and virbr0-nic.  Those are installed by libvirt.  Installing MAAS without libvirt (e.g. without `apt install libvirt-bin`) shows that MAAS doesn't install these elements...